# Every python object has a type,id and a value?

Tags: python, object

Sometimes we define objects as a thing that contains type, id, and a value. Sometimes we say values themselves are objects. These two definitions contradict each other. For eg a=5 we can say there is an int object(a thing) that contains a value 5 and in the other circumstance, we say that 5 itself is an object(Hence in this case there is no such thing as a thing that contains the value 5). These 2 definitions do not conform to each other?? I am going through a python assignment and I was struggling on this for quite some time and I could not find a proper answer on this. Some authors were using the first definition and some are using the 2nd definition.

Comment: With an immutable type -- like an int, or a tuple -- the instance is closely tied to the individual value; you can't change the value without changing to a different instance (and it's undefined whether two variables with the same value will share an instance; the interpreter may do that, or may not, at its choice). Thus, there's effectively no decoupling for immutable types.

Comment: Beyond that, do you have a narrow, specific question?

Comment: "Sometimes we say values themselves are objects. " Who says this? I'm not even sure what it's supposed to mean, at the very least, it is vague and ill-defined. What do you mean by "the 5 itself"? 5 is an abstract, mathematical concept. In the concrete terms of computing, there is some memory that represents the mathematical concept of 5.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, to be honest, most of the people at least in python say that "values are objects". This phrase is not much used in other oop languages as in other languages primitive types are not objects. People generally refer to things as objects for defining complex data types wherein an object has multiple attributes termed as the state of the object. For python "Values are objects" make sense for at least built-in types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python indeed everything is an object, including 5; you can display `id(5)` and `type(5)`.

However for some objects the identity is irrelevant and you care about them only for the value. These objects must be immutable.

Number are this kind of objects... we don't care about this 5 or that 5; the very phrase doesn't sound logical. 5 is only interesting for its value.

For other objects (especially mutable ones) you instead care a lot about identity: this list is not that list, even if both are empty.

While using something like

```
 if x is y: ...
```

would be a very bad idea in Python if `x` and `y` are number or strings, it would make perfectly sense if `x` and `y` are for example `list` instances.
The problem with number identity is that if `x` and `y` are numbers and I write:

```
z1 = x + y
z2 = x + y
```

may be `z1` and `z2` end up being the same object (i.e. `id(z1) == id(z2)` and `z1 is z2` returns `True`) or may be not (i.e. `id(z1) != id(z2)` and `z1 is z2` returns `False`).

For sure however the value of `z1` and the value of `z2` will be the same (i.e. `z1 == z2`) and that's what you care about when using numbers.

Comment: thank you for answering my question and now it makes sense. For objects can I think of the memory space(holding the value) as the object itself(as it conforms to the definition that each object contains a value). Obviously, the size of the memory block will depend on the value being stored(or the type of the object)

Comment: One last thing am I right in saying that most of the people at least in python say that "values are objects". This phrase is not much used in other oop languages as in other languages primitive types are not objects. People generally refer to things as objects for defining complex data types wherein an object has multiple attributes termed as the state of the object. For python "Values are objects" make sense for at least built-in types immutable objects as defining the state of object 5 does not make sense